# Javascript sort divs Alphabetically without destroying CSS Form Style

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

Good evening the community. I was trying to check similar questions and answers about this topic. I found the way to sort order the divs. But the **css style got destroyed**. I don't understand why it's not keep the CSS style?  (I had flex for example, and the new divs sort by Alphabetical was without flex, without styles css)

```
<div class=lignes-1 id=Order onclick="OrderFunction()>
          
            <p class=Nickname>Victor</p>
            <p class=Nickname>William</p>
            <p class=Nickname>Natalia</p>

</div> 


<script>   
function OrderFunction() {
    OrderlistNickName();
    sortThem();
    
  }

  function sortThem () {
  $('.Nickname').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).appendTo('body');
}
</script>

<style>
.lignes-1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 660px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Nickname {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the sorted elements to the body.

You should instead be appending to the element with the `lignes-1` class.

```js
function OrderFunction() {
  sortThem();

}

function sortThem() {
  $('.Nickname').sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.textContent < b.textContent) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }).appendTo('.lignes-1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=lignes-1 id=Order onclick="OrderFunction()">

  <p class=Nickname>Victor</p>
  <p class=Nickname>William</p>
  <p class=Nickname>Natalia</p>

</div>



<style>
  .lignes-1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 660px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  
  .Nickname {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: @Lasticot No problem. If it solves your question, please consider accepting my answer.